# Selecting desired texts from a web table

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating a page using C# with Selenium Web-driver. If I search for "Aaron" then 6 names that start with "Aaron" will show. Is there an option where it allows me to select the desired "Aaron"?

[Please see image below]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhO9B.png)

Comment: Filter by their full name first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the name elements in a list, do a foreach, verify the elements text one by one, if it matches with the specific name you provided, click it, if none of the items match, throw an exception.

```
public void SelectName(string name)
{
    foreach (IWebElement element in NamesList)
    {
        if (element.Text.Equals(name))
        {
            element.Click();
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("No elements with text " + name + " were found");
}
```

if you don't want to click the element, you can change the "Click()" to anything else.

Comment: You should throw an exception after the `foreach` to indicate that the name was not found. Otherwise your script will expect that something was clicked and move on when nothing was clicked and will fail in some unexpected way.

Comment: Also, if you are going to scrape the page for names (to fill `NamesList`), it would be better/faster to just build the locator that searches for the complete name instead of looping through all looking one by one.

Comment: @JeffC awesome, appreciate it!

Comment: @JeffC How would I edit the code above to add in the exception?

Comment: See my first comment... add the exception after the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I did mention that the script would do nothing if it didn't find an element with the text, but as the question author asked for it, i added the exception